# How can i use an exception without the program stopping?

Tags: python

I am using an exception to detect whether a pickle file exists or not. However, I want it to repeat instead of stopping as soon as the program reaches that exception. How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
         try:
            print('\n > loading character...')
            w(1)
            save_game_load = save_game_name + '.pickle'
            pickle_in = open(save_game_load,"rb")
            character_save = pickle.load(pickle_in)
            print(' > character loaded successfully')
            w(0.3)
            print('\n > welcome back',character_save['name'],'!')
            print(' > here are your stats from last time: ')
            print('\n >',character_save)
        except:
            print(' > could not find a file with name',save_game_name)
```

Comment: With a `while` loop? But how will that help you if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: so that if the file doesnt exist, then it will ask you to input the file name again

Comment: You must use a while loop to do so

Comment: If the error is transient for sure then retries are acceptable. I get a lot of value from using tenacity: https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I don't see any `input` in your code... Please provide a [mre]